# how to assign the value of var to text filed in java script by parsing it to float

Tags: javascript, html

I have var a=99.90090 i wan to fix it to only 99 and dislpaly it on text box but the orinigal value of var a should remain same.

I want like this as we do in iphone

```
      SevereEIULabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_SevereEI_Unvaccinated];
```

Comment: i have tried to parsethis and store it in new variable like that i want simple like we do in iphone like i am adding code

Comment: @SankalpMishra i have edited code please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a = 99.90090;

```
b = a.toFixed(0); // 100
b = a.toFixed(1); // 99.9
```

**EDIT**

b = parseInt(99.90090); // 99

**EDIT 2**

```
<input type="text" id="my_field" name="my_field" value="" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
a = 99.90090;
$('#my_field').val(parseInt(a)); 
</script>
```

Comment: i do not want in a new varible but i want to give that direcly to textfiled without using a new var

Comment: If you are using jQuery `$('selector').val(parseInt(99.9999))` for example `$('#my_id').val(parseInt(a))`

Comment: @user1808433 - Then don't assign it to a variable. Just use `a.toFixed(0)` wherever you need to as an expression.

Comment: When I tested `toFixed(0)` will round to up. In this case he need use `parseInt(a)`

Comment: @AllysondePaula can you explain your code in a example as swapnesh has given

Comment: Execute the EDIT 2 example

Answer (score 0):

why so serious.............

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    var value=99.90090;
    testvalue=parseInt(value);
    document.getElementById("atext").value=testvalue;
}
</script>
<input type="text" value="" id="atext" />
<input type="button" onclick="fnc()" value="click me" />
```

Comment: but i do not need new var to make i have 100 values i will make 100 var it will take time

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and let me know if i am wrong with what you are asking to implement -

```
var a=99.90090;

document.write(parseInt(a.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a =99.90090;
temp = parseInt(a);
document.write(temp);
```

check my code and remind me if any changes needed